# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: viewer.loadExtensionAsync is not a function

Tags: reactjs, sprite, heatmap, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

[image: This is the Error I'm getting]

`checkout the code on this link`
`https://codepen.io/vibhav-joshi/pen/KKejEvE?editors=0010`

We are trying to get the heatmap on our revit model but we are unable to show the heatmap. Tried several ways like changing the extensions from getExtensions() to loadExtensions() still nothing is showing in the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method called `loadExtensionAsync` in the viewer API. You can use the [loadExtension](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loadextension-extensionid-options) method which is also asynchronous (so you can `await` it), or [getExtension](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getextension-extensionid-callback) if the extension was already loaded before.

Also, please note that we have recently updated our DataViz demo, https://aps-iot-extensions-demo.autodesk.io, and you can find its source code here: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo.

Comment: So can you tell me how to put your own data in which will connect db.json from backend and will show in the viewr?

Comment: The sensor data is randomly generated on the server-side, specifically in the [iot.mocked.js](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/master/services/iot.mocked.js#L1-L14) file. You can start by modifying the `getSamples` method to return your specific data instead of the randomly generated values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Viewer Documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/), `viewer.loadExtensionAsync()` does not exist. You must use `viewer.loadExtension(extensionId)`.

As the return type is a **promise**, this function is **async** so you should **await** the result like that :

```
const dataVizExt = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization");
```

Another way of doing this, is adding the "Autodesk.DataVisualization" extension in the options of the Viewer when creating the Viewer instance :

```
const config = {
    extensions : [
        "Autodesk.DataVisualization"
   ]
};
        
let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeviewer'), config);
```

Then you should be able to get the extension like that :

```
const dataVizExt = await viewer.getExtensionAsync("Autodesk.DataVisualization");
```

or

```
var dataVizExt;
viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization", (ext)=>{
   dataVizExt = ext;
});
```